# Embedding wordpress into a php page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm looking for a tutorial on how to embed Wordpress into a webpage e.g a php page. I found one such tutorial about a year ago. I remember it split the pages into parts making the main require the rest, one of the requires was the blog posts on the wordpress. I'm looking for this tutorial or something similar. Basically I just want all of my blog updates appearing on a php file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

Answer (score 1):

Just grab the rss feed from your blog and parse it. That should be simple enough.

Comment: This did occur to me but this particular tutorial did something more elegant than this allowing it to be expanded for additional functionality as far as I remember. Good reply none the less.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to display my latest blog posts on my website's home page using SimplePie. My blog is built on WordPress but my home page is coded by hand, so it took me some time to figure out a way to do it. I wrote a blog post about it if you care to check it out. [Displaying WordPress posts on a separate web page](http://blog.thelibzter.com/displaying-wordpress-posts-on-a-separate-web-page). Hope it helps, let me know if you have any questions!